# Replace word with capitalized word

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

If the first words of the line (one or more) are all in CAPs, I would like to replace those words with the capitalized words (using ruby's `.capitalize`). For e.g. "FOO BAR" to "Foo Bar"

I tried the following:

```
line.gsub!(/^([A-Z ]+)/, '\1'.capitalize)
```

and

```
line.gsub!(/^([A-Z ]+)/, "\\1".capitalize)
```

which both did not work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
line.gsub!(/^([A-Z ]+)/) { |w| w.capitalize }
```

In IRB:

```
require 'active_support'
'FOO bar'.gsub(/^[A-Z]+/) { |w| w.capitalize }
 => "Foo bar"
```

or the OP's version:

```
'FOO bar'.gsub!(/^([A-Z ]+)/) { |w| w.capitalize }
 => "Foo bar"
```

For the first two words, this is quick and dirty:

```
'FOO BAR'.gsub!(/^([A-Z ]+ [A-Z]+)/) { |w| w.capitalize }
 => "Foo bar"
```

You can get a little prettier using:

```
'FOO BAR'.gsub!(/^((?<word>[A-Z]+) \g<word>)/) { |w| w.capitalize }
 => "Foo bar"
```

Of course, using the `!` version of `gsub` on a fixed string won't do anything useful.

---

The OP added additional constraints:

```
require 'active_support'

line = 'AFOO BFOO CFOO DFOO e f g'
words = line[/^(?:[A-Z]+ )+/].split.map{ |w| w.capitalize } # => ["Afoo", "Bfoo", "Cfoo", "Dfoo"] 
[words,line.split[words.size..-1]].join(' ')                # => "Afoo Bfoo Cfoo Dfoo e f g"
```

Comment: This works, but only for the first all-caps word. Do you know how to make it work for cases where the first 2 words are all-caps?

Comment: Just need to add the space character in the []. He forgot(?) it in his example.

Comment: I tried with the space as well and it still doesn't work for the second all-cap word.

Comment: Maybe my example in my question makes it clearer. Sorry, and thanks!

Comment: You're changing the rules on us.

Comment: I thought it was clear in the question before. Sorry for the mis-understanding.

Comment: Note that with all of these you can more tersely do: `my_str.gsub( /…/, &:capitalize )`

Answer (score 2):

You want to capitalize all words in line, correct?
Try String#scan instead:

```
line.scan(/\w+|\W+/).map(&:capitalize).join
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm no Ruby programmer, but I can see that you're calling `capitalize` on the string `\1`, which of course is just `\1` again. You will want to look for something similar to PHP's [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) that will allow you to run regex matches through a function - in this case, `capitalize`.